# json java spring rest soapui post 400 error

Tags: java, json, spring, jaxb

So this is my controller which gives error on rest post json with soapui:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientRest implements GenericRest<Client>{
    @Autowired
    ClientServices clientServices;

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientRest.class);
    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public  @ResponseBody Status addEntity(@RequestBody Client t) throws Exception {
        try {
            clientServices.addEntity(t);
            return new Status(1, "Client added Successfully !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error( "Client not added Successfully !", e);
            return new Status(0, e.toString());
        }
    }}
```

Endpoint: http://localhost:8080
Resource: /SpringRestCrud/client/create
Parameters: ?code=code&name=name

erro 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Raw:
POST http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/client/create?code=code&name=name HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

and my client class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")

public class Client implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2540515546630918880L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;//set get removed for better reading
```

Comment: Having the parameters on the URL is a GET (not a POST).  Also, the incoming parameters on the URL are not in JSON.

Comment: You are right Andrew, I try change some options in the soapui and get the stuff working with this: uncheck post query string and choice a media type json with this write bellow the checkbox: {"code":"code3","name":"name3"}. raw is: POST http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/client/create?Client=%7B%22code%22%3A%22code%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22name%22%7D HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 35
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)